# Повторение анимации вылетающего блока

Tags: javascript, анимация, разработка-игр

Я не понимаю, почему не выходит повторить анимацию. То есть при нажатии на пробел я ожидаю, что вылетит столько чёрных блочков, сколько нажатий было совершено, а происходит совсем не так почему-то

```js
 const canvas = document.getElementById('man');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const canvasBullet = document.getElementById('bullet');
    let ctxBullet = canvasBullet.getContext('2d');
    let speedBullet = 0;
    let fightPressed = false;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);

    function fight() {
        requestAnimationFrame(tickBullet);
        console.log('baxxxx');
    }

    function tickBullet() {
        ctxBullet.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let xB = 150 + speedBullet;
        ctxBullet.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctxBullet.fillRect(150 + speedBullet, 125, 10, 10);
        speedBullet += 9;
        if (xB > canvas.width) {
            ctxBullet.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(tickBullet);
    }

    function keyDown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) fightPressed = true;
    }

    function keyUp(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) fightPressed = false;
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false);

    function update() {
        if (fightPressed) {
            fightPressed = false;
            fight();
        }
    }

    setInterval(update, 10);
```

```css
    #man {
        border: solid 1px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
    <canvas id="man" width="500" height="400" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
    <canvas id="bullet" width="500" height="400" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Начнем с того, что вы неправильно используете `requestAnimationFrame`. Его надо вешать бы на весь цикл игры, который будет отвечать за бесконечную петлю. Я его повесил на метод `update`. Что логично. Ознакомьтесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame. При этом `setInterval` не нужен. Зачем он, если у вас есть `requestAnimationFrame`?
- У вас не могло физически вылететь столько "пуль", сколько раз вы нажали клавишу. У вас перерисовка одна. И координаты перерисовываются одни. Как вы при этом хотели сделать несколько? Для этого:

  - создается общий объект "bullet", у которого есть координаты
  - создается массив пуль, куда при каждом выстреле заносится новый объект, а при уход за экран - извлекается

  Уже непосредственно этим массивом и надо манипулировать и проходясь циклом, перерисовывать на холсте координаты каждого из объектов.
- `fightPressed` не нужна. Т.к. при `keyDown` мы просто вызываем метод `fight()`, который заносит пулю в массив, который в свою очередь пробегается по всем элементам в своем методе
- `tickBullet` мы запускаем **всегда** в основном цикле игры. Просто когда массив пуст - то не по чему будет пробегаться.
- манипуляции  `let xB = 150 + speedBullet; ....speedBullet += 9;` - бессмысленны. Если вы уж задаёте скорость, то вы определяете её сразу. Я её вынес в параметры объекта пули.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('man');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasBullet = document.getElementById('bullet');
let ctxBullet = canvasBullet.getContext('2d');
let speedBullet = 5;
//let fightPressed = false;

let bullet = {
  x:150,
  y: 125,
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  speed: 5
};

let bullets = [];

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);

function fight() {        
    bullets.push(Object.create(bullet));               
}

function tickBullet() {        
    bullets.forEach((el, i) => {
        ctxBullet.clearRect(el.x, el.y, el.width, el.height);
        el.x = el.x + el.speed;
        ctxBullet.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctxBullet.fillRect(el.x, el.y, el.width, el.height);            
        if (el.x > canvas.width) {
            ctxBullet.clearRect(el.x, el.x, el.width, el.height);                
            bullets.splice(i, 1);
        }
    });
}

function keyDown(e) {        
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        fight();            
    }
}

function keyUp(e) {    
   // if (e.keyCode === 32) fightPressed = false;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false);

function update() {            
    tickBullet();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function startGame() {
    update();
}

startGame();
```

```css
#man {
        border: solid 1px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
    <canvas id="man" width="500" height="400" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
    <canvas id="bullet" width="500" height="400" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
</div>
```